# Solidity bitwise operation changing a number does not update correctly

Tags: bitmap, solidity, smartcontracts

So I am packing 32 uint8 into a uint256 using bitmap, however when I'm trying to change a value of uint8, it does not update correctly. For example when changing 222 to 221, it becomes 223, I have some idea on why it's happening but I don't know what is the correct way to update it, is it correct to change the uint8 to 0 first then update it? how is it done?

```
uint256 bitmap;
// setting the value for the first time
bitmap |= 222>>0;
bitmap |= 150>>8; 
// and so on...

// updating the value
bitmap |= 221<<0; // when calling this, it becomes 223

// tried to change the value to 0 first
bitmap &= ~(1<<0);
bitmap |= 221<<0;
// still becomes 223
```

Might still not really understand how bitwise operator works, how do I update the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

222 is binary `1101 1110`

221 is binary `1101 1101`

When you do `222 or 221` and assign it to bitmap, both the second rightmost bit and the rightmost bits become 1, and therefore it becomes

223, `1101 1111`

There are many ways you can change a specific byte in an integer, but this can help:

```
bitmap &= ~(0xFF << 0) | (221 << 0) // change 0 to byte index, 0 is the rightmost byte
```

Comment: Ah i see, so i did use the wrong integer with the &= ~(1 << 0), thanks a lot mate